# Slow performance when using workspace in URL

Tags: geoserver

I have one workspaces with 30.000 raster layers in each one.

This request take in average 600ms

```
https://myserver/geoserver/WORKSPACE_A/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0
```

This one take in average 180ms

```
https://myserver/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.0....
```

The response is exactly the same image, same size, same interpolation. The only difference is that the slower one I pass the workspace in the route and the other one no.

Any idea what can be happening?

Comment: 30,000 raster layers sounds like a lot - did you consider a mosaic? as for the speed difference there is an overhead to using a workspace limited request as GeoServer has to go through all the layers to find just the ones it needs